# Cross produkt automaton from automata with different alphabet

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Is it theoretically possible to create an automaton (which then would probably need to be nondeterministic) from two automata with different alphabets (where $\vert\Sigma_1 \cap \Sigma_2\vert \gt 0$)?

Comment: What do you mean by "create an automaton"?

Comment: You can construct a cross product automaton for the intersection/union of two regular languages even if the alphabets are disjoint or intersect in some symbols. It certainly would be nondeterministic but in order to make it deterministic, it only requires a little addition.

Comment: @PeterMcCoy Thank you a lot. I already know how to make a NFA deterministic.  On the internet I only found examples which used the same alphabets and my teacher didn't know either